# Making .command File Automatically cd to the Right Directory

Tags: sh

I need to create a .command file for a project I'm working on.
However, when the .command file is executed, it doesn't `cd` to the directory that the file is in, which is a bit counter-intuitive in my opinion, and is also getting in the way of what I want to achieve. Adding, for example, `cd Downloads/App;` , to the beginning of the program, is not an option because users might have the `App` folder in a different directory.
How do I make it such that `cd "whateverdirectory"` is done automatically at the beginning of the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out:
 `cd "$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")";`